# SQL Server MERGE Slow

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am importing data into SQL Server using the MERGE function, and it is extremely slow.  I am sure this is because I am not doing things the best way, but I am not sure what the best way is.

To explain, I am using Java, I am issuing a batchUpdate with packets of 5k MERGE statements (I have tried various batch sizes).  The merge makes use of parameters, with the values set on the batchUpdate for example:

```
MERGE [MY_DATABASE_TABLE] AS TARGET
        USING (SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  AS SOURCE
```

The ? parameters are replaced with the actual values when I run the batchUpdate.  My MERGE statement does have a number of following conditional checks when matched (if the source is null and the target is not null, for example)

To give an indication of performance, for 38k rows with a straight INSERT statement, the time is 8 seconds, with a MERGE it is 3 minutes.  This time seems to increase exponentially as the number of rows increases (90k rows=23mins).  The same functionality in MYSql is 10 seconds (MySQL uses on duplicate key update).  As SQL Server then locks my database table for the duration of  the MERGE (23mins!) and my 90k rows is a relatively small test file, this performance is extremely undesirable.

This must be something I have not optimised. My 'MERGE On' columns in my Target database table are all Indexed (UNIQUE KEY), so it is not this.  I can not index my source as my source is not a database table.  This makes me wonder if I should first import all the data into a temporary table, and then merge from that?

**My Question is:**
Should the MERGE as I have it be expected to be quicker, or is MERGE only fast if used with temporary tables which are Indexed?

---

Note: I am using the sqljdbc4 v 4.0.x driver

Note: batchUpdate is provided by org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

Comment: There are many factors here which can play a part - and as with all debugging you need to cut variables out of the equation. I'd start with doing a simple experiment. Make two physical tables, fill them up with dummy data but of a realistic amount - and do a merge on it. Does it go slow or fast? If slow, server setup / disk setup / server load etc could be where you should continue investigating. If it's "fast" - then start working towards your application and it's code.

Comment: Hi @Agent96, did the accepted solution here make a significant difference?

Comment: It was much quicker when i used a temporary table, so i imported into a tmp table then merged from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of MySQL - SQL Server's `MERGE` can not ignore duplicate keys. And even if `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is set to `ON` for any unique index on the target table, `MERGE` will ignore this setting.

Yes `MERGE` will be quicker with indexed temporary table.

Comment: Okay - so basically the MERGE from a temp table is VERY fast, doing it by processing 'fixed values' in a SELECT statement, is EXTREMELY slow.  So basically do not do a MERGE unless it is from another table (for non trivial data volumes)

Comment: Yes, precisely so it is. And if even one duplicate by key field - it will not work.